# keep user logged in with phone auth

Tags: java, android

I'm building an android app and I use phone number to sign up a new user.
I want to keep user logged in with his account,
I don't use firebase I used an api for application .how can I do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Use **SharedPreferences**, you can save **boolean** for isLogin(). Check this out [Shared Preferences Guide](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences#kotlin)

Answer (score 0):

Keep an user logged it's not magic, so you have to save somewhere its Credentials (username, token and other things).

- using SharedPreferences:

  - PRO: easy to implement
  - CONS: clearing App's data (and/or cache) will delete it
- using AccountManager:

  - PRO:

    - its Name will be visible in "*Android -> Settings -> Accounts*"
    - clearing cache will not affect this
  - CONS: harder to implement